# inode count via df ~5000x larger than number reported by df

Tags: filesystems, inode

I've been dealing with an issue whereby df is reporting a much larger usage of a partition mounted onto my system from a USB drive.

`df -h` gives:

```
/dev/sdb3       4.6T  4.2T  396G  92% /media/smb
```

Whereas `du -ch` reports:

```
3.7T    .
3.7T    total
```

This led me to investigate inode counts using the same methodology.

From `df -i` I get:

```
/dev/sdb3         19M   17M  1.6M   92% /media/smb
```

and `du -ch --inodes` shows:

```
3.5K    .
3.5K    total
```

Intuitively, knowing the number of files on that partition, 3.5K reads as the correct number, but 17M from `du` seems wildly inflated.

How can I figure out why there's such a large disparity in inodes used?

I've restarted the machine and it persists, and similarly I've restarted all the docker containers on my machine that mount folders from this drive as volumes.

Comment: What's your current directory when running the commands? What type of filesystem is mounted on the `smb` mount point?

Comment: @they I'm in `/media/smb` when running all commands, it's seems to be and exfat mount. `lsblk -f` yields `sdb3       exfat   Exter 5BCA-3CF4                             395.1G    92% /media/smb`